# How to create NTFS partition in ubuntu 13.04

Tags: 13.04, ntfs

I'm am new to this ubuntu but wanna use it. I got a HP laptop with 1tb hard disk in it with windows 7 as default os i had erased my windows and installed ubuntu 13.04 fresh. So can any one help me how to create ntfs partition so i can store my files, movies etc in it please.

Comment: Why?  You already said you got rid of Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowtoPartition/CreatingPartitions

Here is a good manual for creating partitions using Gparted, and includes pictures.

First, install gparted from the software center, or via command line:

```
$ sudo apt-get install gparted
```

Run gparted from your applications, you'll be asked for your root password.

You'll be presented with a list of your exsting partitions. You can re-format a desired partition by right-click and unmount, then right click, and choose a new filesystem. Once done that - click on the green tick above, that will write changes.

You should then have a valid ntfs partition to install Windows. Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

You should install Gparted and create a new NTFS partition

Comment: See i'm new to ubuntu so can u explain me how to use this Gparted

Comment: @Humanth GParted is a software used for creating, deleting, resizing, moving, checking, and copying disk partitions and their file systems. This is useful for creating space for new operating systems, reorganizing disk usage, copying data residing on hard disks, and mirroring one partition with another (disk imaging). (from wikipedia)